# Spring SAML Security - Multiple IDP Metadata configuration for two different ADFS server

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

Is that possible to have multiple IDP Metadata configuration? How do I configure it? 
In my environment I have two different ADFS servers and both has its own Metadata.xml files.

In the securityContext.xml file I have following configuration for my ADFS server IDP selection:

```
<bean id="metadata"
class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
<constructor-arg>
<list>
<bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
<constructor-arg>
<value type="java.lang.String">https://<adfs_server1>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg>
<value type="int">50000</value>
</constructor-arg>
<property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool" />
</bean>
</list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

is it possible to add another entry same as above for two different ADFS servers  like:

```
<bean id="metadata"
class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
<constructor-arg>
<list>
<bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
<constructor-arg>
<value type="java.lang.String">https://<adfs_server1>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg>
<value type="int">50000</value>
</constructor-arg>
<property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool" />
</bean>
</list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean id="metadata1"
class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
<constructor-arg>
<list>
<bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
<constructor-arg>
<value type="java.lang.String">https://<adfs_server2>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg>
<value type="int">50000</value>
</constructor-arg>
<property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool" />
</bean>
</list>
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Please help.

Comment: Can there be two different URLs? For example using a proxy for external users. External URL points to IDP A and Internal URL points to IDP B.

Comment: @DotBatch did you find an answer to your comment?

Comment: @theLearner yes, I had to write a lot of custom code to make it work. But yes.

Comment: Dotbatch, can you guide me or share some snippets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can include as many IDPs as you want. But not by adding multiple `CachingMetadataManager` beans, you should instead include multiple `MetadataProviders` inside a single `MetadataManager`. The configuration could look like this:

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.lang.String">https://<adfs_server1>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="int">50000</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="java.lang.String">https://<adfs_server2>/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                    <value type="int">50000</value>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

You will need to provide a mechanism which determines which of the IDPs should be used when user wants to authenticate. You can do so either by specifying GET parameter `idp` with value of the `entityId` of the selected IDP when invoking the `/saml/login` endpoint, or by implementing IDP discovery.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir.  I tried this yesterday itself and worked well.  Many thanks again.

Comment: @kannan Do you have the code on github? I can't figure out how to invoke the correct IDP. I would like to invoke a specific idp depending on the url they hit.

Comment: Can there be two different URLs? For example using a proxy for external users. External URL points to IDP A and Internal URL points to IDP B.

Comment: Does entity ID have to match the application URL?