# Spring SAML Security - Send request for 2 ADFS servers

Tags: spring, saml, spring-saml

Question to this topic [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993110/spring-saml-security-multiple-idp-metadata-configuration-for-two-different-adf)
How catch invoking the /saml/login endpoint?

Common question: how send request to 2 ADFS and add logic for choosing adfs url?

Answer (score 0):

Configure each ADFS as a separate IDP by importing their metadata (provided they are indeed separate servers, not just a high-availability configuration of the same one) and (e.g.) let use choose which one to use - just like you can see in the sample application. But perhaps I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks, Can i send request to adfs across proxy server (indirect)?
for example: adfs - adfs.com; app - app.com; and proxy server - proxy.com.
Can I send request (app.com->proxy.com->adfs.com), now app.com->adfs.com. What i need to change? App? Metadata?

Comment: There's a simple rule - the URL ultimately accessed by the user (and used to GET/POST SAML messages) must match the one declared in the SAML metadata, unless the recipient is aware of being proxied (e.g. using the SAMLContextLB). Regarding proxy - depends, is it an HTTP proxy, transparent proxy, SSL proxy? ADFS has a component which allows you to HTTP proxy requests to ADFS, instead of going to ADFS directly - just use that and follow Microsoft's manuals, it will work fine.